# Point a main domain using cname

Tags: dns, cname

I need to point a domain using a CNAME to another, but I need to point both as the main domain www.

I think that it is not possible with cname. I need to point a domain to other domain like a cname, but also main domain.

How i can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect an entire domain, you actually want to use DNAME instead of CNAME.  You can do CNAME records too, but you'd need one CNAME for every equal record, whereas DNAME lets you do just one.  DNAME records aren't quite as well supported, however.